# hola no puedo usar wine me aparece esto cuando lo descargo

Tags: linux, debian

No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

```
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 winehq-stable : Depende: wine-stable (= 8.0.1~focal-1)
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba instalando winehq solamente:

```
sudo apt-get install winehq
```

o prueba con esto

```
sudo apt update sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Comment: o prueba con esto: 

sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer]

Answer (score 0):

lo que te ocurre es que tienes dependencias/paquetes rotos esto puede pasar al instalar algun programa nuevo o actualizar

Prueba con  `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing ; sudo apt-get install winehq`

Primero intenta reparar los paquetes e intenta volver a descargar el winehq